# Prove $A \cup B \subseteq C$ using element chasing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Question:

> Give an element chasing proof that for any sets $A$, $B$, and $C$: if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \cup B \subseteq C$. Proof should use case analysis.

I need some help proving this  using element chasing and case analysis. I'm not entirely sure what it means by using case analysis, but I understand how to do basic element chasing proofs.

I am unsure as to how to start this proof because of the required guidelines needed. I might be overthinking it as I usually do, but any push in the right direction is always helpful!

Comment: Case analysis means that when you're trying to show every element of a set has some particular property, you break up several "cases", i.e. you compile a list of several (usually mutually exclusive) "possibilities" about an element of the set, and then show the theorem holds in each case. For example, say I want to show the square of any integer is *not* equivalent to $2 \mod 3$. I might do this by saying, "an integer $n$ is equivalent to $0, 1,$ or $2 \mod 3$." I'd then show that in each "case", $n^2 \not \equiv 2 \mod 3$. You find finitely many options (cases), and proving each.

Answer (score 4):

If $x\in A \cup B $ then either:

- $x\in A$

or

- $x\in B$

If $x\in A$ then by the hypothesis $x\in C$. The same for the case for which $x\in B$.

So, in any case $A\cup B\subseteq C$.

Answer (score 1):

Given some $x \in A \cup B$, there are two cases. It might be the case that $x \in A$ and since $A \subseteq C$ this implies $x \in C$. Otherwise we have $x \in B$ and since $B \subseteq C$ this also implies $x \in C$. Therefore $A \cup B \subseteq C$.